# Laravel, dump-autoload without Shell Access

Tags: php, shell, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have two controllers with the same name:

`app\controllers\CareersController.php` (for public use)
 `app\controllers\Admin\CareersController.php` (for admins)

Because of the naming conflict, I added `namespace admin;` to the admin controller.

Everything works fine locally but when I uploaded the new admin controller to my server, I get an error: `Class Admin\CareersController does not exist`

From what I understand, the fix is:
`php artisan dump-autoload`
and `composer dump-autoload`

However, I don't have Shell access to run those commands and composer isn't installed on the server anyway. So, is there a way to reload the auto-load file without Shell access?

Comment: Can you dump autoload locally and then replace your server's `vendor` directory with your local copy?

Comment: I could. Would there be any unintentional side effects of doing this?

Comment: Nope, however it's not the recommended use of Composer. It's meant to be a dependency management system so you can start a new server and just run `composer install` and get all the necessary requirements / autoload files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238547/run-composer-dump-autoload-from-controller-in-laravel-5/65718344#65718344 i you can trust in this answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You dont need shell access. Artisan includes a `dump-autoload` function. You can just it via a PHP call within your app:

```
Route::get('/updateapp', function()
{
    \Artisan::call('dump-autoload');
    echo 'dump-autoload complete';
});
```

Edit: just noticed you wrote *"composer isn't installed on the server anyway"*. Not sure what will happen - try the command above and let us know.

If it doesnt work - then just run composer dump-autoload locally - then upload your new autoload.php.

As a side point - is there any option to switch servers? You going to keep running into various issues if you dont have command line & composer access. You could just use Forge and spin up a new server on DigitalOcean, Linode etc in less time than it would take to fix this issue :)

Comment: I ended up calling `dump-autoload` locally and then redeployed and it worked. Our deployments use GIT to deploy from local->qa->prod so it is preferential to do any file changes in local environment. I am working to get Shell access anyway though. :)

Comment: if the composer is not installed on the server is says `The command "dump-autoload" does not exist.`

Comment: how this answer  gone accepted . it is wrong answer.   Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException
The command "dump-autoload" does not exist.

Comment: system('composer dump-autoload'); for laravel 8

Answer (score 20):

Run `composer dump-autoload` locally. Then, in your hosting site,
you can update two files, `autoload_classmap.php` and `autoload_static.php`, manually in `vendor/composer` folder. I prefer to copy and paste the added classes from local to the hosting server.

Answer (score 3):

I was using a shared hosting by client's requirements and did not have access to ssh or composer, what I did was to `composer dump-autoload` on my local machine and then I figured that for my project autoloader just updates `composer` directory in my `vendor` directory, so I just re-uploaded that one folder after each `dump-autoload` and not all vendor directory

Edit:

Another pitfall for me that generated the same error but the cause was something else, I develop on Windows machine in which file and directory names are case insensitive when deploying to Linux server, the framework could actually not find my controllers so I changed

`Route::get('/news', 'newsController@index');`

to

`Route::get('/news', 'NewsController@index');`

now it is working, autoload is doing it's job correctly