# Run composer dump-autoload from controller in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I want to run `composer dump-autoload` without shell command in controller.
In laravel 4 I use `Artisan::call('dump-autoload');`
 but in laravel 5 this command not work.

Comment: Did you try `Artisan::call('composer dump-autoload');`? If you want a _real_ artisan command, you need to make yourself comfortable with writing commands (https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#writing-commands)

Comment: Command "composer dump-autoload" is not defined.

Comment: I was thinking that this might happen. You either use native php with `exec` or `system` or better you wright a proper artisan command .. as described in the official Laravel docs.
Keep in mind that `exec` and `system` is mostly forbidden on hosting systems.

Comment: Can you share more details? What do you want to achieve by this? Why not run this on deploying your application?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Artisan is not wrapper for `composer`. Composer itself brings the `composer` command to control itself.

Currently there is no way to call `composer` commands in a *proper* way from Artisan - not even with creating your own Artisan command with `php artisan make:console CommandName`.

Unless you don't want to use PHPs `exec` or `system`, which I highly do not recommend, you better run `composer dump-autoload` on its own.

Comment: There is way to do this with your own command without using `exec` or `system`, check my answer.

Comment: For laravel version 5.3 and above use  `php artisan make:command CommandName`

Answer (score 12):

There is no `Artisan::call('dump-autoload');` command in >= Laravel 5.0, but if you still want to use this command and don't want use solutions with `exec` or `system`, you need create your own command by: `php artisan make:console DumpAutoload` for Laravel version > 5.3 (You need add new command to `$commands` array in `app/Console/Kernel.php`). Then you need inject Composer class to you new command construction:

```
public function __construct(Composer $composer)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->composer = $composer;
}
```

and then you can run `dumpAutoloads()` in `handle()` method:

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->composer->dumpAutoloads();
}
```

Check class `MigrateMakeCommand` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateMakeCommand.php` there is an example command that use it. Here you have my command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Composer;

class DumpAutoload extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'dump-autoload';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Regenerate framework autoload files';

    /**
     * The Composer instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Foundation\Composer
     */
    protected $composer;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @param Composer $composer
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Composer $composer)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->composer = $composer;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->composer->dumpAutoloads();
        $this->composer->dumpOptimized();
    }
}
```

Comment: For the ones using laravel 5.5 and higher. change the Use to use Illuminate\Support\Composer;

Comment: Don't do both `$this->composer->dumpAutoloads()` and `$this->composer->dumpOptimized();`. `dumpOptimized` is the same as `dumpAutoloads('--optimize')`

Comment: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/composer.phar) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/codeintel.biz/:/tmp/)

this is the error that is being thrown.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
system('composer dump-autoload');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a laravel command that uses `Symfony\Component\Process\Process` such as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class ComposerDumpAutoloadCommand extends Command
{
    protected $name = 'composer:dump-autoload';
    protected $description = 'Run composer dump-autoload';

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->dump_autoload();
    }

    private function dump_autoload()
    {
        $process = new Process(['composer', 'dump-autoload', '-o']);
        $process->setTimeout(null);

        try {
            $process->mustRun();
            $this->info($process->getOutput());
        } catch (ProcessFailedException $e) {
            $this->error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can run this for better result. it will give your result like command line.

```
 return  "<pre>". shell_exec ('composer dump-autoload')."</pre>";
```

Comment: Please share more details. Why should there be any need to wrap the result in markup?