# Running composer dump-autoload in a controller does nothing

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm attempting to run `composer dump-autoload -o -d C:\laragon\www\site` inside a Laravel controller using the following (or similar - see below):

```
$command = 'composer dump-autoload -o -d ' . base_path();

exec($command, $output);
```

But when doing this, output is always null/empty, and the status code is always 1. No errors in either the Laravel or PHP logs. The composer files in `vendor/composer` do not get updated. I have also triple checked that the directory exists, even removing the `-d` parameter, which made no difference. Running `composer dump-autoload` in the terminal manually, works as expected, and with no errors.

I have also tried `system()`, `passthru()`, `shell_exec`, but all exhibit similar behaviour.

Additionally, since I'm running the latest Laravel, I have access to `Illuminate\Support\Composer`. I've tried the below code, but again it behaves exactly as the above code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Composer;

// Attempt 1
app(Composer::class)->dumpAutoloads();

// Attempt 2
app(Composer::class)->dumpOptimized();
```

I've been playing with this for a couple hours now, and have been using these sources as reference:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-composer-dump-autload-in-php

[Run composer dump-autoload from controller in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238547/run-composer-dump-autoload-from-controller-in-laravel-5)

EDIT:

After manually adding logging to the `$callback` parameter inside the `Composer::dumpAutoloads()` helper in laravel, I've found that I'm getting the following error:

`local.DEBUG: 'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Composer works in all my other terminals (Windows Terminal, and the embedded PHPStorm terminal). I've also confirmed that Composer is in my environment variables, and that the path for that variable is valid and is the composer bin folder: `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`, Composer is also installed for all users.

Right now I'm wondering if this is some "weird" behaviour on Windows and how it determines what user runs the process when initiated by PHP (or what environment variables the process can see). Unfortunately, I don't have a ready-to-go Linux environment to test this against. I'm aware the `Composer` helper in Laravel uses the Symfony process classes under the hood, perhaps I'm missing something here? Not sure why the PHP `exec` functions, etc, also didn't work though.

Comment: Permissions might be the cause of this. Webserver should not write the files it serves.

Comment: Is there any good reason to dump the autoloader in a running application? Also, why not use the full path to the Composer binary if you don't use a shell that contains a path variable pointing to it?

Comment: I'm building a "modules" system, and when "installing" a module, it unpacks the module into a directory. However, I needed to be able to have composer autoload all the classes in the module (when enabled) and to do that I needed to dump the autoloader.

Comment: I think I approached the issue incorrectly though. After some additional thought, I decided that instead of dumping the autoloader when enabling a module, I'll automatically include the module's autoloader if the module is enabled. It does set a requirement that when installing a module it has to have the composer vendor directory included, but since the vendor directory is essentially the module's dependencies, I don't think that's particuarly a bad thing. Also means I don't have to dump the autoloader or attempt to do any composer sorcery.