# Class 'NotificationChannels\Hubtel\HubtelMessage' not found laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sms, sms-gateway, notification-channel

I got this error while implementing the Hubtel SMS Api.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use NotificationChannels\Hubtel\HubtelChannel;
use NotificationChannels\Hubtel\HubtelMessage;

class SendSMS extends Notification
{
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [HubtelChannel::class];
    }

    public function toSMS($notifiable='yes')
    {
//        echo "hi";
        return (new HubtelMessage)
            ->from("JabClari")
            ->to("+923105149080")
            ->content("Kim Kippo... Sup with you");
    }
}
```

I installed Hubtel SMS channel using this and following proper instructions.

> https://github.com/Norris1z/hubtel-laravel-sms-channel

Please help me

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: All the files are in the server. I am remotely connected to it, how to run command in server? I dont have cpanel

Comment: You'll need to find a way to get ssh access. Talk to your hosting server. Or check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109816/laravel-dump-autoload-without-shell-access